# Make group by in outter join LINQ to entity

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I use Entity Framework-6.
I have this code(outter join, LINQ to entity):

```
        var inspectionSitesConjection = (from st in sites
                                         join ir in inspectionReview on st.Id equals ir.SiteId into g
                                         from subsite in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                         select new GeneralReportViewModel
                                         {
                                             siteName = subsite.Site.Name,
                                             address = subsite.Site.Description,
                                             inspectionDate = subsite.DateReview,
                                             siteType = subsite.Site.SiteType.Description,
                                             frequency = subsite.InspectionFrequency.Name,
                                             status = subsite.IsNormal,
                                         }).AsNoTracking();
```

I need to make group by `siteName` and `frequency`.

Is it pussable to make group by inside LINQ above?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @Ivan, if I have multiples siteId = 5 how can I make it to be appear only once by using group?

Comment: I do understand that. The question was what problem are you facing to implement what you need - it sounds like a standard `group by`. The only thing you need to decide is what will be the result, since group by will return `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>`

Comment: Can you show example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a starting point:

```
var grouped = inspectionSitesConjection
    .GroupBy(item => new { item.siteName, item.frequency });
```

But note that the result (as you may see in [Queryable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/library/bb534492(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation) is no more `IQueryable<GeneralReportViewModel>` but `IQueryable<IGrouping<Key, GeneralReportViewModel>>` where `Key` is anonymous type having `siteName` and `frequency` properties.

I'm providing this just because you specifically asked. It's not quite clear what are you trying to achieve with that query. Also, once you decided to use explicit join, then use the joined table instead of navigation property, and take into account that `subsite` can be null due to outer join.

```
from st in sites
join ir in inspectionReview on st.Id equals ir.SiteId into g
from subsite in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new GeneralReportViewModel
{
    siteName = st.Name,
    address = st.Description,
    siteType = st.SiteType.Description,
    inspectionDate = subsite.DateReview, // problem if subsite == null
    frequency = subsite.InspectionFrequency.Name, // problem if subsite == null
    status = subsite.IsNormal, // problem if subsite == null
})
```